# HTML 5 Canvas text in loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am currently trying to overlay some text on a bar graph. In my JavaScript, I have a loop that runs 13 times to plot the 13 bars on the graph. it works fine, but when I add the line....
bar.fillText(barHeight, barLeft, barHeight)
... it breaks the loop and stops drawing. I did a simple test and I'm able to draw text okay, but for some reason I cannot draw text in my loop, and I do not understand why.

```
//Draw bars
    var i;
    barLeft = 75;
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
    {
        bar = eval("ctx" + [i]);
        barHeight = eval("ht" + [i]);
        bar = c.getContext("2d");
        bar.fillStyle = "#3366cc";
        bar.fillRect(barLeft + barWidth + barSpacing, graphHeight - barHeight, 50, barHeight);
        bar.fillText(barHeight, barLeft, barHeight)
        barLeft = barLeft + 53;
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you would post the code as a [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com).

Comment: As a side note.. what's the purpose of using `eval` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of your code to reflect these changes:

- You just need 1 reference to the context instead of 13.
- `eval` is evil! Get your values from an array instead.
- Adjust where you're drawing your text (y==graphHeight-barHeight-5)

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var bar=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cities=['Wilcox','Cobb','Bartow','Cook'];

var graphHeight=250;
var barWidth=20;
var barSpacing=10;

var heights=[];

for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
  heights.push(parseInt(Math.random()*50)+25);
}

var i;
var barLeft = 35;
for (i=0; i<cities.length; i++)
{
  barHeight = heights[i];
  bar.fillStyle = "#3366cc";
  bar.fillRect(barLeft+barWidth+barSpacing, graphHeight-barHeight, 50, barHeight);
  bar.font='18px verdana';
  bar.fillText(barHeight, barLeft+barWidth+barSpacing+5, graphHeight-barHeight-5);
  bar.font='10px verdana';
  bar.fillStyle='black';
  bar.fillText(cities[i], barLeft+barWidth+barSpacing+5, graphHeight+15);
  barLeft = barLeft + 53;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; padding:20px;}
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```